# Is there a way to detect which request is loaded by which script?

Tags: javascript, html, performance

In order to analyze the third party scripts on our site I'd like to create an overview of all the requests and cluster them. During my research I figured out that there is a performanceObserver Web Api (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceObserver). This seems to be already quite useful. For example you can get an overview over the pages requests in JSON format with:

```
performance
        .getEntries()
        .map(entry => JSON.stringify(entry, null, 2))
        .forEach(json => console.log(json));
```

(Source: https://www.w3.org/TR/performance-timeline-2/)

Unfortunately there is no info about the request's referrer. For example I want to know if the origins url requested something or if an ad script requested an additional script. Is there a way to get this information somehow?

When using the performance tool Speedcurve which is based on webpagetest.org and clicking on a request there is this information available under "loaded by". I don't know if there is also a Web Api or some javascript code for this. I wasn't able to find anything yet.

Comment: Hm, well, this info is available in the "Initiator" column of Chrome's devtools Network tab.  I'm unaware of any way to get that info programmatically though.

Comment: @Amy: Thanks for the tip! It seems that you can't access this information from console but when writing a browser extension you would have access to it  over the Chrome Devtools Network API (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_network)

Comment: That's neat, so have you figured it out, or at least made some headway?

Comment: @Amy: I tried to create a chrome extension but it was an epic fail since I have no experience with this at all and documentation seems to be quite poor. Even with this working example https://www.nine.com.au/tech/2017/11/08/15/31/chrome-dev-tools-part-1 I was not able to pass objects to the console from there. But then I figured out that you can export the chrome waterfall as JSON with rightclicking in there and I guess I will take this and process it.

Comment: Sounds good.  I do not have experience writing extensions, so cannot help.  I am aware though that how extensions works has changed over the years, so there's a lot of obsolete documentation and such out there.  You could edit this question and make it a "how do i make a chrome extension that does _____" type of question though.